# Parse.com query not returning on iOS 64 bit: Unity 5.0, il2cpp

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I have integrated parse.com in Unity app which worked correctly.
Recently I upgraded unity version to 5.0 for 64 bit iOS Apps and parse queries are not returning anymore.
I am using latest Parse SDK i.e. v1.3.4.
I exported to xCode project using il2cpp framework.

Here is code I am trying

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Configuration").WhereEqualTo("Key", "MetaVersion");
query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t->{
    Debug.Log("Never gets printed");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il2CPP is very much a work in progress at the time of this question.  Bug report problems with tight repro projects and they will get addressed.

It is worth noting that you do not need to move to Unity 5.0 for 64 bit support. The same 64 bit support is in 4.6.3, the latest 4.6 at the time of this question.

Update: Unity 4.6.3p1 (http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases) may have a fix for your issue at least in 4.6.  The version notes contain:

> (669983) - iOS/IL2CPP: Allow the LogInAsync method in the ParseSDK to
>   work correctly.

New version of Unity 5 will eventually incorporate that I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

The Parse developers have worked around a number of the IL2CPP issues in v1.3.5 of the Parse SDK. If you have not tried that version yet, I would recommend it.